# How to make an environment created with newtcblisting behave the same as one created by the minted environment?

Tags: environments, tcolorbox, verbatim, minted, tcblisting

I have declared a new envrionment in a class file like this (the complete file exists [here](https://github.com/sujaldev/college/blob/main/pdf/ipu-c.cls)):

```latex
\renewcommand{\theFancyVerbLine}{\parbox{10pt}{\centering\footnotesize\arabic{FancyVerbLine}}}

\newtcblisting{codebox}[2]{
    listing only,
    listing engine=minted,
    minted language=#2,
    breakable,
    enhanced,
    colback=white,
    coltitle=black,
    colbacktitle=white,
    top=0pt,
    bottom=0pt,
    sharp corners,
    title=\textbf{#1:},
    minted options = {
        linenos,
        breaklines,
        escapeinside=||,
        xleftmargin=10pt,
    },
    overlay={%
        \begin{tcbclipinterior}
            \draw [line width=1pt] (frame.north west) rectangle ([xshift=18pt]frame.south west);
        \end{tcbclipinterior}
    }}

\BeforeBeginEnvironment{codebox}{\vspace*{-18pt}}
```

but when I use this environment in my main tex file as below:

```latex
\documentclass{ipu-c}

\begin{document}
    \begin{codebox}{Program}{c}
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    printf("Hello, World!");
    return 0;
}
    \end{codebox}
    \begin{codebox}{Output}{text}
Hello, World!
    \end{codebox}
\end{document}
```

my IDE (PyCharm with TeXiFy IDEA) keeps screaming at me as if the code inside the `codebox` environment is latex code and tries to format it as such, but this does not happen when I use the minted environment. I have two questions regarding this:

- How to fix this such that my IDE recognizes this as a verbatim environment (or whatever the type of environment created by minted is called)?
- Also is it possible to remove the trailing newlines added by either `tcolorbox` or `minted` as seen in the picture below (I already tried the stripnl and stripall options in minted but they're not working): [image: latex output]

Update: I tried the `autogobble` option in minted and it did solve the problem in point 2 but I think it does quite a bit more than what I want, I don't want it to touch anything else besides leading and trailing newlines.

Update 2: It seems like the problem in point 1 is related to the texify idea plugin itself, ensuring that the environment name ends with "code" seems to fix it.

Comment: Please include a complete example (from `\documentclass` to `\end{document}`). Using only what you've given, I get no extra line

Comment: @mbert I've added a complete example.

Comment: I do not get extra lines with your example. Please include the full log file

Comment: @mbert did you use the class file I linked to or the one in the question itself? If using the linked file, that one has autogobble turned on. If not, [here](https://files.sujal.dev/se.log) is the log file.

Comment: Neither produces extra lines for me. Your packages are from 2022, try updating texlive and see if the output is the same

Comment: My distribution doesn't have texlive 2023 yet, I tried running the latest texlive docker image and it does work, thanks @mbert!